# My applications won't appear on my home screen? (android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'am making apps for android using eclipse but suddenly when I was using the emulator the apps stopped appearing on my home screen and when I check in the Application manager they are installed but I can't access them and I tried installing the app on my android phone and the same thing also happened so any clue how to fix this, that would be great. thanks

edit:
The app starts correctly when I launch it from eclipse but the icon won't appear on my home screen so I can't access it

here is my mainfest code:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.Moon.khwallpaper.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.Moon.khwallpaper.Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.Moon.khwallpaper.SET2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET2" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you removed some intents in the manifest? You might want to include some code (such as your manifest). Do you mean it wont autostart or that it's not even in the launcher? If the latter it's most likely that you removed some intents you need in your manifest.

Comment: could u show us your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the intent-filter of your *MainActivity* and changing the *Menu* intent-filter to:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

**EDIT:**

Your logcat suggests that you are trying to start an activity with an action that is not set (or set incorrectly).

It's looking for the action `com.Moon.khwallpaper.SET2` while what you have set is `com.example.wallpaper.SET2`.

I believe changing the latter to the former should work.

Comment: @user3896367 is MainActivity your *main* activity? Crashed with what error? Please be more specific, we're not psychics.

Comment: "Unfortunately, Wallpaper has stopped" that is what it says

Comment: @user3896367 this isn't helping at all. Post the error in your logcat instead.

Comment: @user3896367 try uninstalling your app through `Settings -> Apps -> All -> Your_App -> Uninstall`

Comment: @user3896367 please update question with your current manifest and also your applications package name.

Comment: @user3896367 you are still not using the intent-filters I suggested you use for your MainActivity and MenuActivity...

Comment: my MainActivity isn't what is supposed to be a Launcher

Comment: @user3896367 Then change Menu action to `android.intent.action.MAIN`. Why name an activity Main if it's not main :/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wallpaper.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.wallpaper.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wallpaper.Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wallpaper.SET2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try removing <action android:name="com.example.wallpaper.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />